# Почему при наследовании редактируется значение предка?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование

Написал такой код для примера:

```
FIELD_SIZE = (2, 2)
GAME_FIELD = [[1 for x in range(FIELD_SIZE[0])] for y in range(FIELD_SIZE[1])]


class Field(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)


def clear(field):
    for y in range(FIELD_SIZE[1]):
        for x in range(FIELD_SIZE[0]):
            field[y][x] = 0


field = Field(GAME_FIELD)
clear(field)

print(GAME_FIELD)
print(field)
```

> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

Но, ведь, я редактировал `field`, а не `GAME_FIELD`
По логике же должно получиться

> [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

Как мне редактировать только `field`, что б `GAME_FIELD` оставалась неизменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените строку

```
field = Field(GAME_FIELD)
```

на такое:

```
from copy import deepcopy

field = Field(deepcopy(GAME_FIELD))
```

И наследование тут не при чём, если бы вы так же использовали бы список

```
l = list(GAME_FIELD)
clear(l)
```

то у вас была бы точно такая же проблема.

Тут всё дело в том, что когда вы куда-то передаёте список, то у вас там будет именно сам этот список, а не его копия. И если вы манипулируете его элементами, то эти изменения будут видны всюду, где используется этот список.

Поэтому когда вам нужна отдельная копия списка, не связанная с изначальным списком, его нужно явно копировать. А если в нём есть вложенные списки - то копировать обязательно с помощью `deepcopy`.

Comment: Спасибо, с Вашей помощью стало все понятно